# Redirecting an AWS elasticbeanstalk to another elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new in these kind of situation. My manager wants to redirect this url curaconnector.com/providerbeta to the another url.The another url is just an environment ID url. Is this possible?

Help me guys. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not redirect Elasticbeanstalk to another URL if there is only one instance in the stack but if you are using DNS for Elastic Endpoint then just update DNS server entry and add NEW Elastic stack endpoint against curaconnector.com.

If you are running more then one instance in the stack then it possible.

If the LB is created with Stack then

Go to Load Balancer -> Edit instance -> remove old Stack instance and add new one -> save

[image]

If the LB configured manaulay

Goto Load balancer -> select LB -> Select existing Target group -> Edit instance -> remove Elastic 1 instance and select Elastic 2 instance from the target group

If you set record for LB in route 53 or any other DNS server then you need to update Elastic stack 2 Load Balancer Endpoint against curaconnector.com/providerbeta